# Firefox - show width and height in developer console like in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In chrome if you select and element in the developer console, you will see the width and height of the element.

[image]

On firefox there is no such info and you have to lookup the CSS code.

[image]

Is there a plugin which extends the developer tools with this feature?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/tr/firefox/developer/). 
It comes with great features and simplicity.